# Array printing out garbage values

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I have an excercise were I have to write a recursion function that calculates e^x using a formula. I managed to do that, but the exercise says that I have to store the results in an array, this is where I hit the wall, this is my code:

```
double exp (double x, int n, int* fakt, double* xpot) {

static double result;
static int i;
static double *A;
A  = (double *) malloc(n * sizeof(double));

if (i == n)
{
    for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        cout << A[k]; //this prints out garbage values
    return result;
}


if (i != 0 || i != 1)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    *fakt = *fakt * j;


}
*xpot = pow(x, i);


result += *xpot / (double)*fakt;
A[i] = result;

*fakt = 1;

i++;

return exp(x, n, fakt, xpot);
```

}

I would pass the array as the function argument, but the task specifically says that:

```
double exp (double x, int n, int *fakt, double *xpot);
```

is the prototype.
My question is why the loop prints out garbage values, and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: `A[k]` is uninitialized when you print it. You need to set it to a value.

Comment: You use `malloc` to allocate memory for `A` (in C++!) and immediately after that you enter a loop that prints out the values of `A`. Why do you expect anything other than garbage values?

Comment: this is my first semester, and first time using c++ so I'm a bit behind, but why is it bad using malloc in c++? That's what they thaught us.

Comment: Also why does it enter the loop immediately when there is an if statement above it?

Comment: `malloc` just provides the address of a block of bytes of memory that have been made available to the program to use. Problem 1: You need to convert this pointer to the correct type and ensure you got the correct number of bytes to store the object. Problem 2) `malloc` does nothing with that memory, so whatever values were previously stored in this memory are still in this memory when your program gets it. This often appears to you as garbage because you have no way to interpret what, if anything was last in that memory.

Comment: Problem 3: `malloc` is a C function. C does not deal in classes with constructors and destructors, so `malloc` does no know that a constructor may need to be called to correctly initialize data, so no constructor is called. For a complicated datatype that can only function correctly if the constructor is called, allocating it with `malloc` is usually fatal (see [Placement `new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) for one important case where it is not). In C++ `new` solves 1 and 3 and through solving 3 it also often solves 2.

Comment: Missed one problem: After `malloc` you need to test the returned pointer. If it is `NULL`, `malloc` was unable to provide the required storage. A great many bugs are the result of forgetting that test. The default behaviour of  `new` is to throw an exception on failure, making the failure, usually, easier to diagnose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not initialize the values of `A` thats why there is garbage printed.

Also:

- `if (i != 0 || i != 1)` is equal to `if (true)`.
- Each call to your `exp`function will leak a good amount of memory ... `A` is never
  `free`d
- `xpot` and `fakt` might be `nullptr`, what could go wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "I didn't initialize the values of A"?